# Create two output images in one command in ImageMagick

Tags: command-line, imagemagick, thumbnails

I have this very well working code that creates 3x3 tiles, sharpen and adds watermark.

```
input.jpg -resize 300x250 -write mpr:tiler +delete -size 900x750 tile:mpr:tiler -sharpen 0x.7 wartermark.png -gravity southeast -geometry +0+0 -composite output1.jpg
```

Besides saving this result, I want it to make a cropping (thumb) 750x750px, scaled to 100x100px and saved as output2.png.

I have tried a lot but can't get it to work. It's ok with an +0+0 offset in the cropping.

**EDIT**: I want to add something like:

```
... -crop 750x750+0+0 -resize 100x100 output2.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

In Imagemagick, you can output multiple images, if you use combinations of parenthesis processing, clones and +write. In this case, as Mark Setchell pointed out, you just need the write command. Here is your code as follows. I have included your request for crop and resize.

For Windows with IM 7

```
magick input.jpg -resize 300x250 -write mpr:tiler +delete -size 900x750 tile:mpr:tiler -sharpen 0x.7 wartermark.png -gravity southeast -geometry +0+0 -composite +write output1.jpg -gravity center -crop 750x750+0+0 +repage -resize 100x100 output2.jpg
```

If using Imagemagick 6, replace magick with convert.

Comment: Why `parentheses clone thumbnail write close parentheses null` and not just `thumbnail output2.jpg`? Just trying to understand.

Comment: It didn't work with the parenthesis or without. I'm using Imagemagick 7 on windows 10. Am i supposed to be able to process the thumbnail after output1.jpg is written, just straight ahead?

Comment: Try my modified code, now that you have specified what you want for output2 and your IM version and platform. Note that when you say to crop at 750x750, your input image is not square. So the second output2 will not have the same aspect ratio as output1.

Comment: Mark, you  are correct. It is not needed. I often do that just for clarity and as in the case at https://imagemagick.org/Usage/files/#write. I will correct my answer to make it simpler.

Comment: It's still not working. Whatever i put after saving output1.jpg just breaks the whole processing. It even doesn't save output1.

Comment: Just substituting my images works for me with V7 on Windows 10. Have you put " " around your file paths?     "filepath"

Comment: What is your exact Imagemagick version, date of the version? How did you install it? Perhaps there is some issue with your version or it is too old. Post your exact command with the images with their paths so we can see what you are using. Did you start your command with the word, magick. You do not show that in your post above.